# How to make states in F#

Tags: f#

F# beginner here.
Did I say beginner ? This is my second day with F# )

I want to make only two states for record: Valid and InValid;
I'd like to make illegal state unrepresentable.

Here is my code:

```ml
module Foo =
    type Success = Success of string
    type Pending = Pending of string
    type Failure = Failure of string

    type Valid = Valid of string
    type InValid = InValid of string

    type StateGranted = { Status: Valid; Msg: Success }
    type StateDenied = { Status: InValid; Msg: Failure }

    type State =
        | StateGranted
        | StateDenied

    let status = Valid "Valid"
    let msg = Success "Success"

    let state = { Status = status; Msg = msg } // I have an error here

    printfn "result %A" state
```

So, how can I create record of type `State` ?
If user wants to create

```ml
let state = { Status = Valid; Msg = Pending } // compiler should throw an error here
```

I have TypeScript background

P.S. I have found very useful [article](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-making-illegal-states-unrepresentable/) but I don't understand it yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest tackling a project in F# where it's clear what you want to achieve. You need to make it clear to yourself what the legal data is.

1. It's not clear what the `Success` type represents. Is `Success "Invalid"` legitimate? This goes for all of the first five types and these can be deleted.
2. When you are trying to define `state` you probably intend for both StateGranted and StateDenied to be valid possibilities. But these are not of the same type. You need to define a single type that represents the things that `state` could be.

This reduces your code to something like:

```ml
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
type State =
    | Granted // possibly you mean for there to be string-like data here
    | Denied
    // or possibly there are string functions of it like
    //member t.ValidityString =
    //    match t with
    //    | Granted -> "Valid"
    //    | Denied -> "Denied"
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer also is very good. I just need to switch my mind from TypeScript to F# type system )

Comment: Yes, I agree with this. You need to unify the type, and possibly rethink the whole approach. Then you can tackle it with either pattern matching or active patterns if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error because the type inference cannot distinguish between the two records of different types but same properties. You need to prefix one of the members:

`let state = { StateGranted.Status = status; Msg = msg }`